# New GMaps renderer not loading tiles until the map is dragged in iOS phonegap app

Tags: ios, cordova, google-maps-api-3, phonegap

I maintain a mobile WebApp wrapped using phonegap and encountered an issue with new renderer update of GMaps API.
Some time ago this new renderer was introduced, and although according to docs it shouldn't break anything, map doesn't render until dragged around a little bit.

Everything worked fine on the previous version of GMaps API (v3.31), but after update it works only in browser, and not working when compiled to xCode project.

The app changes pages by hiding and showing corresponding divs, so I used to implement 'trigger resize' hack to reflow GMaps. With the new renderer it seems deprecated, and indeed in the browser the map is loading just fine with or without resize trigger.
But when I compile my app with phonegap, the map tiles and info at the bottom don't render, even though markers are working, and all the listeners seem to be working too (for example I can place new markers with double click). The tiles only load after I drag the screen around, and then map is working just fine.

I tried to programmaticaly pan the map around after load, but this doesn't change anything. Triggering 'resize', 'bounds_change', and 'drag' events doesn't help either.

I use just the GMaps javascript API, not the cordova googlemaps plugin.

[Here's how the maps page looks just after loading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GlNzm.png)

Comment: We are encountering the same problem with our app. Were you able to find a solution for this issue?

Comment: For now our solution was to change our loading order for this page, with GMaps initializing only after the page is shown.

Comment: Check coordinate.